# How to prevent Rails from "cUrl post injection attack"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, post, curl, code-injection

My website is being nuked by new signups and new posts some of which don't even have user.id associated with.

How do I solve this? What code should I add to the user#new page and/or post#new page.

If it would help, please check my repo: https://github.com/nixor/cpblog

Comment: Do you have a live link to the form? Without seeing it, I'd say add a captcha to the registration form.

Comment: solved now by adding validation, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to validate that a `Post` has a user. You can start by adding validation that the user exists.

In the Post model add:

`validates :user, presence: true`

You may also check for the existence of attributes in your controller in order to notify the user.